# Android Finger Painting stretch on rotate

Tags: java, android

I am making a finger painting app. Using `Paths` I have created a canvas for users to draw lines on as if finger painting. I have saved the paths and reload them when the device is rotated to landscape mode. However with the new screen dimensions part of the drawing is now off screen.

What is the best way of adjusting the points in my path to stretch the image across the new screen dimensions so the user doesn't loose any of their drawing off screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue like this:

```
                if(getWidth() > getHeight())
                {
                    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
                    RectF rectF = new RectF();
                    p.computeBounds(rectF, true);
                    scaleMatrix.setScale(1.6f, .6f,0,0);
                    p.transform(scaleMatrix);
                }
                canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
```

Where `p` is the path.

Comment: I have same problem. I used scaleBitmap in onSizeChange() Please give me full description.